# How to install particular folder from file set in startup action?

Tags: file, directory, directory-structure, install4j

I want to install single folder which contains static data required in installer in STARTUP action how can I achieve this required behavior.In startup that folder should get installed in installation directory but single folder only not all of files.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept all my answers to your previous questions, that makes it easier for future visitors. Now it looks as as though the answers are not helpful (0 points, not accepted).

Comment: Yep I Have done that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "Startup" actions are running, no files from the distribution tree are available.

If you need files at that point, you have to add them to

Installer->Custom Code & Resources

then they will be available in the `${installer:sys.resourceDir}` folder.

If that is inconvenient, you have to move your actions after the "Install files" action, then the files from the distribution tree will be installed.

Comment: Suppose i have added one directory in custom code it will be bundled in user.jar now how can I access files from user.jar in scripts?

Comment: user.jar only contains scripts, the single files you add on "Installer->Custom code & Resources" are extracted to the `${installer:sys.resourceDir}` folder. So you can access such a file via `new File(context.getVariable("sys.resourceDir").toString() + "/myFile.txt" )`